# Difficulty in running MACOS application using py2app

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, py2app

Heym, I am trying to convert my python tkinter code to a standalone Mac application. I am using py2app and when i run the necessary command line code of `python3 setup.py py2app` the build succeeds.

However, when i try opening the .app file that is generated in the dist folder, I get this error:

```
Launch error
See the py2app website for debugging launch issues
```

Any sort of guidance on this would be valuable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters, have you checked the advice on the [py2app website](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugging.html) on debugging launch issues?

Comment: Yes, I have. It is not as helpful as I thought.

Comment: Did you try to launch the application directly, from a terminal window, as described on the web page? Did that produce any error messages? If so, what were they?

Comment: So tried it just now by putting this command in the CLI dist/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp but it dos not work. It shows the same error as before.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing the output of the CLI; Typically, there is a better error message

Answer (score 0):

I used to use py2app but it kept giving so many errors that I had to change my method. I now use PyInstaller which is much easier to use and doesn't have nearly as many problems. I would recommend trying PyInstaller but if you could also help explain the problem better that would be useful. if you want better debug on the problem go into the application package and traverse to the macos folder. click on the main unix executable and it should give more help on the issue as it literally gives a terminal where problems are printed.

Comment: So I tried using PyInstaller before using Py2App but its gives this error **The application "MyApp" can't be opened**

Comment: Can you open the apps and add the unix executable log to the question so I can help out more?